# How to store a linked list (entity with next and previous keys) in a database using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've created a database model with two foreign keys. One pointing at previous and one at next item.

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SomeModelId { get; set; }

    public int? PreviousStepId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreviousStepId")]
    public SomeModel PreviousStep { get; set; }

    public int? NextStepId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NextStepId")]
    public SomeModel NextStep { get; set; }
}
```

In my context I've declared some options:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel >()
            .HasOptional(c => c.PreviousStep)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel >()
            .HasOptional(c => c.NextStep)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When I try to save the set of those entities I'm getting this exception:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

Am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to save such a model?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have that issue because your Fluent Api configurations are overwriting your Data Annotations, so with your current configurations EF doesn't know which FK would be used for each relationship. Remove those Data Annotations and call `HasForeignKey` method in your configurations:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel >()
            .HasOptional(c => c.PreviousStep)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c=>c.PreviousStepId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel >()
            .HasOptional(c => c.NextStep)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c=>c.NextStepId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: @Landeeyo, same error? That's weird, Did you remove the data annotations? Anyways you could also try using just the data annotations and removing the Fluent Api configurations. It would be the [same](http://roland.kierkels.net/c-asp-net/how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-entity-in-code-first/). Try to not merge Fluent Api and Data Annotation in the future, could case problems like this ;)

Comment: Yes, the same error. I've removed annotations on one class, not on every model in my project. Maybe that's the reason. That's good advice to don't mix annotations and fluent. Thanks.